# get label text from DataListItem Template

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am making an item template in a DataList which shows images in it. I have a button in it to display details of the image.

On button click I want to get the label text which is in that template portion . how can I do this?

This is my code :

```
     <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="217px" Width="221px"
             ImageUrl='<%# Eval("image") %>' />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("image") %>' 
                ></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="90px" 
                onclick="Button1_Click" />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: posted answer try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataListItem dr = (DataListItem)((Button)sender).Parent;

        Image Image1 = (Image)dr.FindControl("Image1");

    }
```